# Narrow Search in public knowledge base is not working?

Tags: knowledge, articles, public-group

I am unable to get the Narrow Search section to appear on the PKB. I've checked all settings and permissions and nothing's jumping out at me.
[image]
I follow the below Step to do this.

1. From Setup, click Create > Custom Labels.
2. Click Edit next to PKB2_Category_Group_Label_1 enter a value to appear on your public knowledge base.
3. Enter a value to appear as a filter on the left side of your public knowledge base.
4. Click Save.
5. Repeat for PKB2_Category_Group_Label_2 and PKB2_Category_Group_Label_3.

But The filter options are not showing.

Help me how i can solve this.... Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

The "Public Knowledge Base AppExchange App Guide" speaks to it, but not very well.

[image]

Filter options can only be Data Categories out of the box.

Based on how far along you are in your screenshot, try these step to give you an idea of how it works:

1. GO TO "PKB 2 Settings" tab.
2. Select the setting linked to you site and click on the "PKB Web setup" tab.
3. Set "Category Group 1" to the "Group Unique Name" of one of your active Data "[image: Category Groups]" (NOT "Categories")
4. Set "Root Category 1" to "All"

Now you should see all the categories in the group.